# how can i change READ only permission of folder

Tags: 12.04, permissions

I'm new to ubuntu , I'm using ubuntu 12.04 LTs

the permission on the file like

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Oct 9 14:16
```

Comment: What file ? Most system files should only be edited as root. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Comment: file of application but it has read only permission

Comment: See my comment, you still have not identified what file. More likely then not you should edit it as root rather then changing permissions. See the link I gave you.

Comment: sorry for my misunderstanding , i didn't got what in the link , it's a file of data and got it's data when run the application

Answer (score 7):

If you have a permission problem where you need to get write access to a  root-owned directory and the solution looks like "give everybody write permission" you're probably doing something critically wrong.

There are a dozen solutions to this but which is write really varies based on what the data is.

- Allow the **group-owner write permission** and add yourself to that group (or change the group to a group you are in). This is common with `/var/www/` scenarios where a webserver and a real user both need to be able to write to a directory.

  ```
  sudo usermod -aG www-data $USER
  sudo chgrp www-data /path/to/directory
  sudo chmod -R 774 /path/to/directory
  ```

  But **don't** add your user to the root group; that's silly.
- **Change the owner to your user**.

  ```
  chown -R $USER: /path/to/files
  ```

  If no other users (inc system) need access to the directory, make it yours. Obviously this won't work if you're sharing these files with other processes on the system (like a webserver or a system-used application).
- [**Use ACL**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs). This is a fine-grain permission framework that allows you to add named users to the permissions rosta. Very handy but a bit fiddly to set up.

  Still, don't muck around here. If the file/directory isn't meant to be owned/edited by random people, don't open things up so anything running under your user can edit it.
- **Do nothing**. Use `sudo`, `sudoedit` et al to edit the files and leave their permissions well alone. If they're root-owned for a reason, leave them like that. This is most true of settings. The tiny inconvenience of asking your password is keeping your system safe.

Comment: i need to try to change this folder permission because i have error because of it in my code ! if you can help I'll appreciate that

Comment: If you can better explain what directory it is, somebody can tell you the best option. I was serious, you can do this the wrong way and make things much worse.

Comment: /home/st/myapplication/the folder

Comment: I'd go with taking ownership. `chown -R $USER: ~/myapplication`

Comment: I'd also look at why this was created with root permissions in the first place. If you ran your application with `sudo`, and it wrote it, that might explain it. It's best not to run thing with `sudo` unless they *really* need it. That's much easier to control if it's *your* application.